# Mongodb query searching through array not working using python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

My data in mongoDb is stored as following:

```
 {
    '_id': ObjectId('59f1989a83add71bf5ae6867'), 
    'data': [              
        {'name1': {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val3'}, 
        'name2': {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val3'}, 
        'name3': 'searchValue'},
        {'name1': {'key1': 'val4', 'key2': 'val5', 'key3': 'val6'}, 
        'name2': {'key1': 'val4', 'key2': 'val5', 'key3': 'val6'}, 
        'name3': 'otherValue'},
     .
     .
     .
     ]
    }
```

And my query in python is

```
cursor = db.database.find({ "data.name3": "searchValue" }).sort([( "_id" , -1 ) ]).limit(1)
```

Above query returns whole data. 
I need following output.

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId('59f1989a83add71bf5ae6867'), 
    'data': [              
        {'name1': {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val3'}, 
        'name2': {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val3'}, 
        'name3': 'searchValue'}
    ]
}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit your question with the exact output you required ?

Comment: @PSJ question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
cursor = db.database.find({ "data.name3": "searchValue" }, {"data.$" : 1}).sort([( "_id" , -1 ) ]).limit(1)
```

Comment: Its working. I need extra help as well. My there are other fields other than data array in my record. This query doesn't show those fields. Can you help me with that please?

Comment: You can add them into the projection options:
Ex: 

```cursor = db.database.find({ "data.name3": "searchValue" }, {"data.$" : 1, "other_filed_x" : 1, "other_filed_y" : 1}).sort([( "_id" , -1 ) ]).limit(1)```